# Declaring new xsl stylesheet after transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, msxsl

Right now I have an xml database with all of my products, but I wish to pull each one out individually into it's own xml file. Right now I can do this, but the problem I am having is that I need to declare a new xsl stylesheet after the transformation.

I have tried my best and looked over questions for hours, but still no luck. If anyone is able to help me out, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output a new xml-stylesheet processing instruction.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="orig.xsl"?>
<doc>
    <test/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name()='xml-stylesheet']">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
            <xsl:text> type="text/xsl" href="new.xsl"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new.xsl"?>
<doc>
    <test/>
</doc>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I am relatively new to xml and xsl, and did not know about xsl:processing-instruction